# cv.fillPoly generating zero arrays, not reading inputs

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I have

`blank = np.zeros(shape = im.shape, dtype = np.float32)`

which generates

```
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

I have `[label2poly[label]]` which is dtype('int32')

```
[array([[ 716,    1],
        [ 710,  281],
        [ 727,  322],
        [ 756,  369],
        [ 793,  399],
        [ 863,  406],
        [ 952,  416],
        [ 978,  412],
        [ 416,    1]])]
```

When I try `cv2.fillPoly(blank, [label2poly[label]], 255)` it outputs

```
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)`
```

where it should have been something like

```
array([[  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0., 255., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0., 255., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       ...,
       [  0., 255., 255., ..., 255., 255., 255.],
       [  0., 255., 255., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.]], dtype=float32)
```

I am trying to create multiple masks. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Initialization of `blank`:

```
blank = np.zeros(shape=[5, 5], dtype=np.float32)
print(blank)
```

Output:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Initialization of `label` followed by a call to `fillPoly()` which uses is as a mask to fill `blank` with **255** at specific positions:

```
label = np.array([[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]], dtype=np.int32)

cv2.fillPoly(blank, [label], 255)
print(blank)
```

Output:

```
[[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0. 255. 255. 255.   0.]
 [  0. 255. 255. 255.   0.]
 [  0. 255. 255. 255.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```